# Ubuntu 21.04 beta on Mac Mini won't boot after updates

Tags: mac, beta, mac-mini

I've been trying to set up an old Apple Mac Mini as an Ubuntu desktop machine for testing, etc. I was able to install the last LTS - Ubuntu 20.04 - and distros based upon that such as Mint, however with Ubuntu 21.04 beta it's a different story.

Ubuntu 21.04 installs fine, and installs updates during the install.  Come time for reboot or a power on, however, I just get a white screen.  No GRUB menu, no messages, nothing.

If I install Ubuntu 21.04 without applying updates, it works fine, so what is breaking the install? I've tested with and without drive encryption, and it makes no difference. Am I missing a step after updating?

Comment: There appear to be "issues" also with the iso where K3B appears unable to burn to DVD reported to Launchpad through the bug reporting facility [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+filebug) It just says Write Error.

Comment: I have found with my experiments with small and compact computers that replacing an OS, like Mac OS, with another system does not always work. It depends entirely on what the newly installed system supports, in accordance with hardware (such as AMD or Intel). Ubuntu 21.04 may not support your processor or graphics yet... I may be wrong, that is why I am not posting this as an answer. Maybe there is something on the release notes: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221